# php.ini modifications has no effect on joomla

Tags: server, joomla

I have a netbook with a recently installed ubuntu server 12.04 64-bit.
I have (only) installed Joomla on it (version 2.5) and now I am trying to tweak the php.ini settings so I can install jomsocial onto joomla.

I have changed these settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 8M
```

to this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

in all php.ini-files in my system. Thats six files, found using 'locate':

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/usr/share/doc/php5-common/examples/php.ini-development
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production-dist
/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.cli
```

I have double-checked that these files actually contain the new settings.

Still, joomla does not recognize the new settings, stating that upload_max_filesize is still only 2M and post_max_size is still only 8M

The same is true after a complete restart of the server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you installed apache on your computer?? Or are you using a tool like xampp??

Comment: The central settings in php.ini files can be overruled in .htaccess files. Those affect the directory they are located in and all subdirectories of that directory. Because of the leading dot in the filename many file managers don't show .htaccess files (they are "hidden"), so it's easy to overlook them.

My advice would be to put a small PHP file into the directory where you like to install Joomla to. This PHP file should contain nothing but <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Calling that file in your browser should give you a lot of information about the PHP settings in that specific directory.

Comment: apache: yes (as joomla is running fine)
xampp: no
I have tried putting a .htaccess in /var/www/joomla with 'upload_max_filesize = 20M' and 'post_max_size = 20M'. It didn't help.
This is the URL I use for checking PHP settings through Joomla:
http://my-ip/joomla/administrator/index.php?option=com_admin&view=sysinfo

Comment: did you check if there are any joomla CMS settings which could set limits to it?
and with no offend, but did you actually restart apache2 to make an affect to any of those changes?

Answer (score 0):

Run a PHP script in your browser containing this `<?php phpinfo();?>`. Then search for this string: 'Loaded Configuration File'. The value of this is the location of the loaded php.ini. You can check if you have really updated this file or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. Everything in the configuration file is correct. The php.ini file I edited was also the correct one, but no matter what I did, it just wouldn't work. (But do check you're editing the correct file since you have like several .ini on your system, and Joomla might be usng a special one or has it's own settings that overrides the main config.)

It turned out there was this PHP *suhosin* patch that was preventing such changes to take effect in the configuration file. It is for "security reasons." You can disable this  somewhere, but I cannot recall how to do that right now. Maybe you can search on Google.

Oh by the way, my issue was that in one of this upload pages I made, I could not upload  more than X number of images/files in one go.